# Filtering a dataframe according to datetime column of other dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, filtering

I have two dataframes, denoted by df1 and df2. The df1 has 6 columns and df2 has 4 columns. The df1 has a column date that the smallest unit is second, but in the df2 is the hour. I am going to filter the df1 according to the df2. It means, I need to extract all records in a df1 that has the same hour as the df2.

**Sample of data for more clarification**

```
df1:                                  df2:

Date (yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss)           Date (yyyy-mm-dd hh:--:--)

2016-03-01 1:02:03                   2016-03-01 1:00:00
2016-04-01 1:03:04                   2016-04-01 2:00:00
2016-05-01 10:04:05                  2016-05-01 3:00:00
2016-05-01 11:07:08                  2016-05-01 4:00:00
```

**The desired output is:**

```
df1: 

2016-03-01 1:02:03
2016-04-01 1:03:04
```

Only the first two rows in the df1 are extracted because their hours exist in the df2.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Second row match in sample data?

Comment: Thank you for your response but I am not sure about your question. In the df1, the first two rows' hours are 1 which is the same as the first row in df2 which is again 1.

Comment: I got it, I think need also match dates.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`Series.dt.hour`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.hour.html) for extract hours with [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df2['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date'])


df = df1[df1['Date'].dt.hour.isin(df2['Date'].dt.hour)]
print (df)
                 Date
0 2016-03-01 01:02:03
1 2016-04-01 01:03:04
```

If need match dates with hours use [`Series.dt.floor`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.floor.html) for match `df2['Date']`:

```
df3 = df1[df1['Date'].dt.floor('H').isin(df2['Date'])]
print (df3)
                 Date
0 2016-03-01 01:02:03
```

EDIT: For check how working hours and floor function create helper columns:

```
print (df1.assign(hour=df1['Date'].dt.hour, floor=df1['Date'].dt.floor('H')))

                 Date  hour               floor
0 2016-03-01 01:02:03     1 2016-03-01 01:00:00
1 2016-04-01 01:03:04     1 2016-04-01 01:00:00
2 2016-05-01 10:04:05    10 2016-05-01 10:00:00
3 2016-05-01 11:07:08    11 2016-05-01 11:00:00

print (df2.assign(hour=df2['Date'].dt.hour))

                 Date  hour
0 2016-03-01 01:00:00     1
1 2016-04-01 02:00:00     2
2 2016-05-01 03:00:00     3
3 2016-05-01 04:00:00     4
```

EDIT1: Problem was with timezones in `df2['Date'`, solution is remove them by [`Series.dt.tz_localize`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.tz_localize.html):

```
df3 = df2[df2['Date'].dt.floor('H').dt.tz_localize(None).isin(df1['Date'])]
```

Comment: Thank you for your response and comments. I used pd.to_datetime to change the type of date column to date and I performed your code, but it doesn't filter the data. My question is, before following your code should I do anything else? I am sorry I am almost a novice in pandas. Would you elaborate a bit, please?

Comment: @AsaYa - so need match dates and hours? Or only hours?

Comment: Yes I need to date and hours

Comment: @AsaYa - One idea, can you try `df3 = df1[df1['Date'].dt.floor('H').isin(df2['Date'].dt.floor('H'))]` ?

Comment: I tried it but it doesn't return anything.

Comment: @AsaYa - It is weird, 2 possible problems I see - `pd.to_datetime` working correct? Are not swapped days and months? And for second - is possible not match dates between both DataFrames? In another words - e.g. in one dataframes are data only for 2022 and in another only for 2016?

Comment: Actually, I did double check and unfortunately, both of your proposed possible problems are not in my case.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249823/discussion-between-asa-ya-and-jezrael).